# Refactoring nested foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, refactoring

Can you help me refactor this block of code? I'm quite having a hard time to decide how can I refactor nested for each loop or not use foreach loop at all.

```
$matcherResults = [];
foreach ($resultItems as $reqId => $resultItem) {
    if (empty($resultItem)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($resultItem as $reg => $data) {
        if (empty($data)) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($data as $regs => $regData) {
            if (empty($regData)) {
                continue;
            }

            $matcherResult = new MatcherResult(
                $regData,
                null,
                $reg,
                $reqId
            );

            array_push($matcherResults, $matcherResult);

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried doing this but unable to come up with the MatcherResult object.

```
 foreach ($resultItems as $reqId => $resultItem) {
     $resultItem = array_filter($resultItem, function($resultItem) {
         if(!empty($resultItem)) {
             return true;
         }
     });
 }

 foreach ($resultItem as $regs => $value) {
     $matcherResults = array_filter($value, function($value) {
         return !empty($value);
     });    
 }
```

EDIT: 
As requested.
Here is a sample of resultItems.

```
Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [test1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [database] => test1
                                [active] => 1
                                [reg] => test1
                                [full_name] => fname1 lname1
                                [image_url] => image.png
                                [last_name] => lname1
                                [first_name] => fname1

                            )

                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: Show a sample of `$resultItems`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I've added sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one of the lower levels could be a null instead of an empty array? If empty is just checking for an empty array, you could do this:

```
$matcherResults = [];
foreach ($resultItems as $reqId => $resultItem) {
    foreach ($resultItem as $reg => $data) {
        foreach ($data as $regs => $regData) {
            if (!empty($regData)) {
                $matcherResult = new MatcherResult(
                    $regData,
                    null,
                    $reg,
                    $reqId
                );
                array_push($matcherResults, $matcherResult);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be more of cleaning the code without using foreach loops.

Comment: hmm, I was thinking of a recursive function, but it's kind of tricky since you need the $reqId and $reg keys...

Comment: Is your issue with the foreach loops themselves or the fact that they are nested? If it's the nesting that's an issue, you could encapsulate the inner loops into functions. It would probably end up being more code and I think it's arguable if it would make it more readable in the end.

Comment: Hi @khartnett. I've decided not to break the nested foreach. Anyway, to answer your question, my issue with this is that they are nested. Thank you for answering though.